Calling a C# callback with a cpp struct in argument from cpp using cppsharp
I want to call a C# function in C++, the function takes a C++ struct as argument which is converted into a C# struct with CppSharp, but it doesn't seem at all trivial.
Here's what I tried :
The struct in C++ :
struct MyStruct {
    float a;
    float b;
}

The struct in C# generated by CppSharp :
public class MyStruct : IDisposable
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 8)]
    public struct __Internal
    {
        internal float a;

        internal float b;

        [DllImport("__Internal", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "_ZN8MyStructC2ERKS_")]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        internal static extern void cctor(IntPtr __instance, IntPtr _0);
    }

    internal static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<IntPtr, MyStruct> NativeToManagedMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<IntPtr, MyStruct>();

    protected bool __ownsNativeInstance;

    public IntPtr __Instance { get; protected set; }

    public unsafe float A
    {
        get
        {
            return ((__Internal*)(void*)__Instance)->a;
        }
        set
        {
            ((__Internal*)(void*)__Instance)->a = value;
        }
    }

    public unsafe float B
    {
        get
        {
            return ((__Internal*)(void*)__Instance)->b;
        }
        set
        {
            ((__Internal*)(void*)__Instance)->b = value;
        }
    }

    internal unsafe static MyStruct __CreateInstance(IntPtr native, bool skipVTables = false)
    {
        return new MyStruct(native.ToPointer(), skipVTables);
    }

    internal static MyStruct __GetOrCreateInstance(IntPtr native, bool saveInstance = false, bool skipVTables = false)
    {
        if (native == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (NativeToManagedMap.TryGetValue(native, out var value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        MyStruct myStruct = __CreateInstance(native, skipVTables);
        if (saveInstance)
        {
            NativeToManagedMap[native] = myStruct;
        }

        return myStruct;
    }

    internal static MyStruct __CreateInstance(__Internal native, bool skipVTables = false)
    {
        return new MyStruct(native, skipVTables);
    }

    private unsafe static void* __CopyValue(__Internal native)
    {
        IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(__Internal));
        *(__Internal*)(void*)intPtr = native;
        return intPtr.ToPointer();
    }

    private unsafe MyStruct(__Internal native, bool skipVTables = false)
        : this(__CopyValue(native), skipVTables)
    {
        __ownsNativeInstance = true;
        NativeToManagedMap[__Instance] = this;
    }

    protected unsafe MyStruct(void* native, bool skipVTables = false)
    {
        if (native != null)
        {
            __Instance = new IntPtr(native);
        }
    }

    public unsafe MyStruct()
    {
        __Instance = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(__Internal));
        __ownsNativeInstance = true;
        NativeToManagedMap[__Instance] = this;
    }

    public unsafe MyStruct(MyStruct _0)
    {
        __Instance = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(__Internal));
        __ownsNativeInstance = true;
        NativeToManagedMap[__Instance] = this;
        *(__Internal*)(void*)__Instance = *(__Internal*)(void*)_0.__Instance;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true, __ownsNativeInstance);
    }

    protected internal virtual void Dispose(bool disposing, bool callNativeDtor)
    {
        if (!(__Instance == IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            NativeToManagedMap.TryRemove(__Instance, out var _);
            if (__ownsNativeInstance)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(__Instance);
            }

            __Instance = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}

The generated C# structure works perfectly when I need to call C++ from C# but the reverse doesn't work, I tried this :
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MyCallback(MyStruct myStruct);

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("MyCppLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void RegisterCallback(MyCallback callback);

        public static void MyFunction(MyStruct myStruct)
        {
            // Use myStruct here
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegisterCallback(MyFunction);
        }
    }
}

extern "C" {

typedef void (*MyCallback)(MyStruct myStruct);
__declspec(dllexport)
void RegisterCallback(MyCallback callback)
{
    MyStruct myStruct
    myStruct.a = 1.f;
    myStruct.b = 2.f;
    callback(myStruct);
}

} // extern "C"

But this doesn't work because the conversion between the C++ struct and the C# struct for this direction is not possible. I've tried replacing MyStruct with MyStruct.__Internal in my C# code and it works, but I can't access fields in the structure without using reflections because all the fields are internal, but I don't want to use reflections.
So how can I achieve what I want?

is cppSharp really worth the effort? I expected regular p/Invoke to handle simple structs and delegates.

Good question, the problem is that there are a lot of c++ structures that I use and they change very often so I need to automate the bindings as much as possible to avoid wasting all my time maintaining them.
